# How to get objects in between two selected objects from Json array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var allUsers = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}]
var  selectedUsers = [{id:1},{id:4}]
```

How would I return this?

```
var remainingUsers = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}]
```

Comment: i think your expected output is wrong

Comment: @NarendraChouhan, Thanks, I updated my expected result.

Comment: are you sure , please check it again

Comment: Yes, exactly. that is what I'm looking

Comment: @mepraveenk If you want to return between 1,4 also having 1,4 is like: 1,2,3,4
Check my answer.

Comment: @Onurgule, It won't work if I choose id after 1 as start object

Comment: @mepraveenk, Can you check whether this is what you want https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/Yzypdmz (Look at console)..

Comment: @mepraveenk I changed the code. Change splice to slice and it will work.

Comment: @mepraveenk please check my answer hope that will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will work for you

```js
var allUsers = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }, { id: 5 }]
var selectedUsers = [{ id: 4 }, { id: 1 }]

function compare(a, b) {
    let comparison = 0;
    if (a.id > b.id) {
        comparison = 1;
    } else if (a.id < b.id) {
        comparison = -1;
    }
    return comparison;
}
selectedUsers = selectedUsers.sort(compare)
var remainingUsers = allUsers.slice(allUsers.findIndex(x => x.id == selectedUsers[0]['id']), allUsers.findIndex(x => x.id == selectedUsers[1]['id']) + 1)
console.log(remainingUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this approach

```
var allUsers = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}]
var  selectedUsers = [{id:1},{id:4}]
function getRemaining(allUsers, selectedUsers){
  var rem = [];
var start = false; 
var stop = false;
allUsers.map((x)=>{

  if(x.id == selectedUsers[0].id){ start = true;  rem.push(x) }
  if(x.id == selectedUsers[1].id){ stop = true;  rem.push(x) }
  if(start && !stop){
    rem.push(x)
  }
})
 return rem
}
getRemaining(allUsers, selectedUsers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var remainingUsers = allUsers.slice(allUsers.findIndex(x=>x.id == selectedUsers[0].id),allUsers.findIndex(x=>x.id == selectedUsers[1].id)+1)
```

You can use slice.

```js
var allUsers = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}]
var  selectedUsers = [{id:1},{id:4}]

var remainingUsers = allUsers.slice(allUsers.findIndex(x=>x.id == selectedUsers[0].id),allUsers.findIndex(x=>x.id == selectedUsers[1].id)+1)
console.log(remainingUsers);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make an example on your given values. please have a look.

```js
var alluser =  [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}];
var selected =  [{id:1},{id:4}];
var left_users = new Array();

function check_matchuser(ref_id){
  var count = 0;
  $(selected).each(function(key, value){
      if(value.id==ref_id){
        count++;
      }
  });

  if(count>0){
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
}//end of check

$(alluser).each(function(key, usersvalue){
    
    var check_status = check_matchuser(usersvalue.id);
    if(check_status){
      var temp_data = {'id' : usersvalue.id};
      left_users.push(temp_data);
    }
});

console.log(left_users);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry my English is not very good,Maybe you can gets the start and end subscripts and then USES the splice() method.

```js
var allUsers = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4},{id:5}]
var selectedUsers = [{id:1},{id:4}]

function getBetweens(allUsers,selectedUsers){
    var start = allUsers.findIndex((item)=>{
      return JSON.stringify(item)==JSON.stringify(selectedUsers[0])
    })
    var end = allUsers.findIndex((item)=>{
     return JSON.stringify(item)==JSON.stringify(selectedUsers[1])
    })
    betweenArray = allUsers.splice(start,end+1)
    return betweenArray
}
console.log(getBetweens(allUsers,selectedUsers),'gets')
```